# docker-compose up results in empty volume folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've read through many posts regarding mounting empty volumes, but I still don't get it. With the `docker-compose.yml` file, I ran the `docker-compose up --build` command, and I could see the container showed up in the docker desktop app, but the `dockerReport` remained empty.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM cypress/base:16.13.0
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install
RUN $(pnpm bin)/cypress verify
RUN ["pnpm", "run", "report"]
```

And here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  cypress_test:
    container_name: cypress_container
    image: cypress_compose
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .\Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .\dockerReport:\app\cypress\results
      - .\dockerReport:\app\mochawesome-report
```

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/WodenWang820118/Udemy-Cypress-Testing), an Angular real-word app I forked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Exec the container and create a new file under /app/cypress/results, it should sync the file to your Docker report, also, in your docker-compose add this to the bottom of the file : volumes : # break line and indent right dockerReport: {}

Comment: Volumes are not mounted when building an image, they are only used when actually running a container.

Comment: okay, so I ran the command `docker build -t cypress_compose ` to build an image first, and I can run the image `cypress_compose`. @Shachar297 However, when I ran the `cypress_container`, it immediately stopped.

Comment: I ran the image in the background successfully, and I took out the `build`, replacing it with my built image, i.e., `cypress_compose`. However, the container stopped immediately. I was using the container to get the testing report out, rather than opening a lasting service. Is that the reason I bumped into this behavior?